# Alias to call model class in artisan tinker

Tags: laravel, namespaces, laravel-artisan, laravel-7

This question might sound silly, but I really wish to know if there is a way to solve the problem of long model path in artisan commands.

I have a models organized in the following structure:

```
`app\Models\Auth\User.php`
```

And in the User model, I define the namespace as this:

```
namespace App\Models\Auth;

class User extends Authenticatable
{

}
```

Now every time I need to access that model, for example in artisan tinker command, I need to write this:

```
>>> Models\Auth\User::create([..]);
```

If I omit the full path, I just get the error `failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

Is there a good way to give an alias to the model classes so that I can easily access it everywhere?

Is the `config/app.php` a good place for that? I never saw anyone putting models in aliases section and I'm not sure if it's a good idea.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I just realized that it comes out of the box, all I need to do is run the following command:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

And that will refresh the autoload class definitions.

Comment: Why does this work? Turns out the dump-autoload command does not download anything new, but just regenerates the list of all known classes that need to be included in the project. This list is stored in `/vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php`.

Answer (score 3):

### Or just

```
composer du

composer dumpa
```

`du = dumpa = dump-autoload`